# Django: conditional URL patterns?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'd like to use a different `robots.txt` file depending on whether my server is production or development.

To do this, I would like to route the request differently in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   // usual patterns here
)

if settings.IS_PRODUCTION: 
  urlpatterns.append((r'^robots\.txt$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'robots_production.txt', 'mimetype': 'text/plain'}))
else:
  urlpatterns.append((r'^robots\.txt$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'robots_dev.txt', 'mimetype': 'text/plain'}))
```

However, this isn't working, because I'm not using the `patterns` object correctly: I get `AttributeError at /robots.txt - 'tuple' object has no attribute 'resolve'`.

How can I do this correctly in Django?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
if settings.IS_PRODUCTION: 
  additional_settings = patterns('',
     (r'^robots\.txt$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'robots_production.txt', 'mimetype': 'text/plain'}),
  )
else:
  additional_settings = patterns('',
      (r'^robots\.txt$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'robots_dev.txt', 'mimetype': 'text/plain'}),
  )

urlpatterns += additional_settings
```

Since you are looking to append `tuple` types , `append` does not work.
Also, `pattern()` calls the `urlresolver` for you. In your case you were not, hence the error.

Comment: `urlpatterns` is not a tuple. `patterns` method returns a list so append may do.

Comment: @PauloBu You are right - but what i meant was, you have to concatenate  `tuple` types

Comment: Oh I see!, I get it know :)

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.8 and up, adding URLs is simple:

```py
if settings.IS_PRODUCTION:
    urlpatterns += [
      url(r'^robots\.txt$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'robots_production.txt', 'mimetype': 'text/plain'}),
    ]
```